# ¿que parte del código de una pagina se ejecuta de nuevo al cargar caché?

Tags: php

Saben si alguna parte del frontend o backend no es estático, sino que se ejecuta de nuevo cuando se carga caché?
Gracias

Comment: no queda claro lo que preguntas

Answer (score 1):

No tengo muy claro la pregunta que estas formulando, pero...
Normalmente dependiendo el navegador que utilices, usan cache, para las cargas de webs que mas sueles frecuentar por optimización de carga.(con posibilidad de desactivar la cache)

Te dejo un link sobre la cache de los navegadores: 
http://faqoff.es/que-es-la-cache-del-navegador/

Otra forma de que se tenga habilitada la cache es según la configuración del servidor que esta "ofreciendo" el servicio.

Por ejemplo en el fichero .htaccess
de Apache para mas info http://evelb.es/blog/php-htaccess-y-memoria-cache/
, sino también en la configuración básica de **php.ini**,
informacion del fichero: http://php.net/manual/es/opcache.configuration.php

Aún asi el código programado se ejecuta de nuevo, lo único que no se ve porque la parte del HTML(con los datos incluidos) se extraen de cache.

Comment: Hola Yasti. Gracias. Ya conocía lo que me compartiste. El asunto es que necesito saber si alguna parte del código de una página guardada en caché se ejecuta de nuevo al abrir lo que se tiene en el caché. Lo digo porque necesito utilizar caché, pero cuando trato de hacer una consulta tengo que actualizar mi página para que aparezcan los resultados de la búsqueda.

Comment: Hola Yasti, en Stack Overflow no hace falta el uso de firmas, taglines o saludos porque cada aporte que hagas ya está “firmado” con tu tarjeta de usuario que apunta a tu perfil, y solo crean ruido innecesario en la publicación. Lee [¿cuál es la conducta esperada de los usuarios?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) para más información.

Comment: Algún aporte Álvaro? Te lo agradecería.